# Calculations by Hand

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the least non-negative residue of:

(i) $5^{18}$ mod $11$

(ii) $68^{105}$ mod $7$

(iii) $4^{47}$ mod $12$

(iv) $66^{75}$ mod $19$

C++ code failed... I'm trying to do by hand now. Maple has this functionality, but I don't have Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ works fine if you do it right. This function calculates and prints $b^p\pmod{m}$ for any non-negative $b, p,$ and $m$:

```
// calculate b^p (mod m)
unsigned powmod(unsigned b, unsigned p, unsigned m)  
{
  unsigned s;
  if (p == 0) return 1;

  s = powmod(b, p/2, m);
  s = (s*s)%m;
  if (p % 2 == 1)
    s = (s*b) % m;
  return s;
}
```

So to get it to calculate and print $5^{18}\pmod{11}$, use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  cout << powmod(5, 18, 11) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. This is interesting. I don't think I've yet covered unsigned. I'm taking the second of three C++ courses offered here at the UC. What is an unsigned data type?

Comment: `unsigned` is just an integer type that can't be negative.  It's not important here; `int` would work just as well.

Comment: Also, how could this code be modified to find the L.N.N.R.?

Comment: How is that different from what it does?

Comment: Thank you, MJD. Till this I've just been making clock diagrams and spiraling outward.

Answer (score 5):

[Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is a good friend.  It says for $a$ not divisible by a prime $p$, $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$  That can knock the $18$ down to $8$ in the first one (which then just needs squaring three times), the $105$ down to $3$ in the second, etc.  The third yields to $4^2\equiv 4 \pmod {12}$

Python also has the function pow(a,b,c) which returns $a^b \pmod c$

Answer (score 0):

For each of them, start small and look for patterns.  $66 \pmod{19}, 66^2 \pmod{19}, 66^3\pmod{19},\ldots$

Comment: $9,5,7,6,16,11,4,17,1,9,5,\dots$

Comment: After you get 1, it will necessarily repeat...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. It's really not as hard as it looks.

$5^2 = 25 \equiv 3\pmod{11}$.

$5^4 = \left(5^2\right)^2\equiv 3^2= 9\pmod{11}$.

$5^8 = \left(5^4\right)^2\equiv 9^2= 81\equiv 4\pmod{11}$.

$5^{16} = \left(5^8\right)^2\equiv 4^2=16\equiv 5\pmod{11}$.

So $5^{18} = 5^{16}\cdot5^2 \equiv 5\cdot3 = 15 \equiv 4\pmod{11}$.